# Was Zod's house symbol in Man of Steel inspired by the one from "Red Son"?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

While watching clips from "**[Man of Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_(film))**", I noticed that Zod's house symbol (the logo on his chest) looks very much like the symbol used in "[Red Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Red_Son)". For those who haven't read it, Red Son is an [Elseworlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elseworlds) title where baby Kal-L crashed in the Soviet Union instead of Kansas. When he became Superman, he adopted as his chest symbol the sickle-and-hammer logo of the Soviet Union:

[image]

**Has anyone involved with the production of "Man of Steel" commented on this similarity, or on where they got the inspiration for the various house emblems?**

Comment: I believe that Zod's face may be a response to your question :)

Comment: @EdmundDantes - lol yeah I had a hard time finding a picture of Zod that clearly showed the logo,  and even then I had to highlight it in PS to make it more visible. It was only coincidence that the two images feature the same pose, but I liked the symmetry of it despite his goofy expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of references to socialist/communist symbology in the movie. I haven't thought deeply about it enough in context to the entire film, story and character development - but throughout the film you'll see many stage settings and art that references soviet era iconography. One in particular is where Kal is in the Kryptonian ship and the back story is being told by his father.

Then there are also the themes of freedom to choose one's destiny as opposed to society choosing it for you. Left right dichotomy. Zod's convictions contrasting to Kal's.

Watch [the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5bB96Mwidc) where Kal meets his father's hologram in the ship.

> ...Every child was designed to fulfill a predetermined role in our (kryptonian) society. As a worker, warrior, leader and so on. Your mother and I believed Krypton lost something precious. The element of choice, of chance. What if the child dreamed of something other than what society had intended for him or her? What if a child aspired to something greater? You were the embodiment of that belief Kal, Krypton's first natural birth in centuries.

The citizens of Krypton are engineered in artificial wombs. This is likely an allusion to the engineered citizens in the novel Brave New World by Aldous Huxley. A central theme of Brave New world as per [this](https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/05/why-brave-new-world-is-no-longer-the-terrifying-dystopia-it-used-to-be/) article is:

> the deliberate homogenization of the human species by the state in a manner reminiscent of a factory assembly line. What’s more, as an admirer of Thomas Malthus, Huxley was also concerned about human overpopulation, a problem he feared would be dealt with in a draconian manner by an authoritarian power.

Freeze frame on that video at 2:34. Then google images "khujand lenin statue close up".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Zod's symbol is most likely a callback to Kryptonese, the Kryptonian language used in the comics from 1986-2000. [image]

The language used a syllabary instead of an alphabet, and the syllables never actually translated into anything. However, if you look to the bottom of the chart, the symbol

[image]

looks an awful lot like Zod's emblem. Furthermore 'zg' is the closest we get to 'Zod' in any Kryptonian alphabet.

*Source: http://kryptonian.info/bridwell-turniansky/alphabet.html*

*The source of my source: http://kryptonian.info/bridwell-turniansky/about.html *

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you told us specifically where you got the alphabet table.  Is it from a website?  Did you scan it from a particular comic book?  Draw it from memory?  What?

Answer (score 0):

Remember Superman is a Jewish story. Zod's symbol is [Zayin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zayin) in cursive Hebrew. Zod in Hebrew is Zayin, Vav, Dalet.

[image: Cursive Zayin]

Comment: This would be a much stronger answer if you could provide an image of what the Zayin symbol looks like, and what it means.

Comment: Seems fairly close. I'll put the link in the post.

Comment: https://shlomosnewdrash.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/zayin.png

Comment: @Valorum Your picture was much better and closer than the horrible thing I found on Wikipedia.

Comment: Feel free to use it. I got it from here; https://shlomosnewdrash.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/daily-aleph-bet-zayin/

Comment: @Doomfrost: Seems pretty similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hebrew_letter_Zayin_handwriting.svg (via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zayin#Hebrew_zayin )